# What does ?. exactly check?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new to dart and often see code like "subscription?.cancel();", What does the symbol actually check? Is it like a non null check? Can it be used for widgets as well? And what happens if it is null?

Comment: see [this](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#other-operators) and press `^F ?.`

Comment: Thanks! That helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is for Conditional member access - Like `.`, but the leftmost operand can be `null`; example: `foo?.bar` selects property `bar` from expression `foo` unless `foo` is null (in which case the value of `foo?.bar` is null).

Thanks @pskink :)